# GaussianNB :- ValueError: The sum of the priors should be 1

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian

What i am trying to do?

I am trying to train the dataset which has 10 labels using GaussianNB classifier but while tunning my gaussianNB prior parameters i am getting this error:-

File "/home/mg/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 367, in _partial_fit
    raise ValueError('The sum of the priors should be 1.')
ValueError: The sum of the priors should be 1.

Code for this:- 
    clf = GaussianNB(priors = [0.08, 0.14, 0.03, 0.16, 0.11, 0.16, 0.07, 0.14, 0.11, 0.0])

You can see the sum is clearly 1 but it showing me this error, can you point the error.

Comment: Can you share the complete the code besides the above mentioned line ? Maybe the problem is something else. I tried initializing the classifier with your priors and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a pretty bad design-decision within sklearn as they are doing the usual **don't compare floating-point numbers** stuff ([what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlt4TwnfXVAhUDPRQKHZEIAkQQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.itu.dk%2F~sestoft%2Fbachelor%2FIEEE754_article.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFe3XjAF5kBbdK_GEwVnZyAbsQJMQ)), which surprises me (as sklearn is usually high-quality code)!

(I don't see any wrong usage on your end, despite using a list. The docs call for an array, not array-like like in many other cases, **but** their code is doing the array-conversion nonetheless)

[Their code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L363):

```
if self.priors is not None:
    priors = np.asarray(self.priors)
    # Check that the provide prior match the number of classes
    if len(priors) != n_classes:
        raise ValueError('Number of priors must match number of'
                         ' classes.')
    # Check that the sum is 1
    if priors.sum() != 1.0:
        raise ValueError('The sum of the priors should be 1.')
    # Check that the prior are non-negative
    if (priors < 0).any():
        raise ValueError('Priors must be non-negative.')
    self.class_prior_ = priors
else:
    # Initialize the priors to zeros for each class
    self.class_prior_ = np.zeros(len(self.classes_),
                                 dtype=np.float64)
```

So:

- You give a list, but their code will create an numpy-array
- Therefore `np.sum()` will be used for summing
- There might be **fp-math related numerical-errors in summing** like in your case

  - **your sum is technically != 1.0; but very close to it!**
- fp-comparison `x == 1.0` is considered bad!

  - numpy brings `np.isclose()` which is the usual approach of doing this

Demo:

```
import numpy as np

priors = np.array([0.08, 0.14, 0.03, 0.16, 0.11, 0.16, 0.07, 0.14, 0.11, 0.0])
my_sum = np.sum(priors)
print('my_sum: ', my_sum)
print('naive: ', my_sum == 1.0)
print('safe: ', np.isclose(my_sum, 1.0))
```

Output:

```
('my_sum: ', 1.0000000000000002)
('naive: ', False)
('safe: ', True)
```

**Edit:**

As i think that this code is not good, i posted an issue [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9633) which you can follow to see if they comply or not.

[numpy.random.sample()](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/52a7efe1f2d0be6adb75d09babe6f203906ecfcb/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1123), which also takes such a vector, is actually doing a fp-safe approach too (numerically more stable summation + epsilon-check; but not using `np.isclose()`) as seen [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/52a7efe1f2d0be6adb75d09babe6f203906ecfcb/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1123).